# Override min_value and max_value in IntegerField Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

```
class A:
  min_v = 1
  max_v = 15
  number1 = IntegerField(min_value=min_v, max_value=max_v)

class B(A):
   number2 = IntegerField(min_value=A.min_v, max_value=A.max_v)

class C(B):
  min_v = 2
  max_v = 20
```

How to make both `number1` and `number2` to be in range from 2 to 20 in class `C`?

I'm thinking about two ways:

1. In `__init__` redeclare `self.fields['number1']` like `IntegerField(min_value=self.min_v)`
2. Set `self.fields['number1'].min_value=self.min_v` in `__init__` and override `setattr()` to add validator.

What is the best and the cleanest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to add these bounds as validators to the  the bounds in the `__init__` method of `class A` and `class B`. This will make these transparent to `C` and furthermore `C` can for example define another `IntegerField` for that name and thus specify a different widget for that:

```
from django.core import validators

class A:
    number1 = IntegerField()
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        number1 = self.fields['number1']
        number1.validators.append(validators.MinValueValidator(self.min_v))
        number1.validators.append(validators.MaxValueValidator(self.max_v))
        number1.widget.attrs['min'] = number1.min_value = self.min_v
        number1.widget.attrs['max'] = number1.max_value = self.max_v

class B(A):
    number2 = IntegerField()
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        number2 = self.field['number2']
        number2.validators.append(validators.MinValueValidator(self.min_v))
        number2.validators.append(validators.MaxValueValidator(self.max_v))
        number2.widget.attrs['min'] = number2.min_value = self.min_v
        number1.widget.attrs['max'] = number2.max_value = self.max_v
```

Comment: I thought about it, but it is not passed to widget attrs.

Comment: @AndrewFount: that why you need to append the validators: Django only looks at this when you *construct* a form field. This thus means that if you later set the `.min_value` and `.max_value`, it will not validate properly at the backend side. The `.min_value` and `.max_value` are necessary for the bounds at the *frontend*, since these will be used for a `<input type="number" min="..." max="...">`.

Comment: I mean, that widget attrs also should be added: number2.widget.attrs.update({'min': self.min_v, 'max': self.max_v})